# How can we see the actual code line while debugging using lldb?

Tags: gdb, lldb

I am seeing asm while debugging using lldb, is their a way to see the c/cpp code line equivalent to it ?
Please see below image for more info

[image: debugging image]

Comment: How did you build a.out?  Did you tell it to generate debug info?

Comment: g++ xyz.cpp then lldb ./a.out

Comment: If that "g++" is gcc, then how about adding -g (per https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html)?

Comment: great. it work and nice link provided, will go through it. Thanks